# C array of pointers to double

Tags: c++, arrays, malloc

I'm getting a memory problem in c++ code, for sure I'm wrong but I don't get the problem. I've declare an array of three pointer to double and allocate memory.

```
double *myDoubles[3];

for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
   myDoubles[i]= (double *) malloc(1000*sizeof(double));
}

myDoubles[2][999]=10.55;
```

Whats wrong?

**EDIT**

As @EdHeal comments and also @PhilippKiener I should not be using malloc at all. But it's difficult to forget malloc before 25 years with it.
After all my problem was another bug in another place and actually I was writing out of limits :). My fault!

Comment: In C you do not cast `malloc` - it is bad - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: What is the nature of the memory problem which you are getting?

Comment: @Jay The problem is that i'm getting memory corruption in other variable when I operate with my double, but I does not look like I'm doing a index out off limits assignation like myDoubles[2][1000] or similar things.

Comment: @EdHeal It is c++ not c. sorry I edit the tags, but I have read de thread, and and include #include <stdlib.h> and the problem goes. In c++ I have to put the cast. but I don't understand why the program compiles but works wrong.

Comment: If C++ - Why are you using `malloc`? You should be using `new` or better still `std::vector`

Comment: @EdHeal you are right, but I'm very old with old manners

Comment: myDoubles[2][999]=10.55; -- This statement is correct for the memory which you are allocing. Can you post the complete code to see if problem exists elsewhere?

Comment: Do you free the allocated arrays later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: don't cast the pointer `malloc` returns. `void*` to (in your case) `double*` is implicit (and expected), casting it explicitly is generally considered bad practice.

Now on to your problem; `malloc` allocates the given number of bytes and returns a pointer to those bytes. You allocate 1000 bytes, but what you want is to allocate enough bytes for 1000 `double`s. The reason for your error is that a `double` is larger than a single byte - it's 8 bytes. You can get the size of a type with `sizeof(type)`; to allocate enough memory for your 1000 `double`s, you'd therefore have to change the line inside the loop to:

```
myDoubles[i] = malloc(1000 * sizeof(double));
```

To get to know the size of the type on your system, you can put

```
printf("Size of double: %d", sizeof(double));
```

In your code.

**Edit:**

Now, since you're working with C++, you should not be using `malloc` at all. C++ makes life easier and gives you `new`!

The allocating line should be

```
myDoubles[i] = new double[1000];
```

The nice thing abour new is that it does not need the size supplied... you give it a type and an amount; it computes the bytes needed for you. But beware, instead of `free` you should use

```
delete[] myDoubles[i];
```

Comment: Sorry again @PhilippKiener I did question bad. bad tag, and a mistake in malloc example, in the code it is ok. I have to cast because is C++

Answer (score 2):

You allocated 1000 bytes each time instead of 1000 doubles.
what you should do is:

```
malloc(1000 * sizeof(double));
```

Your complete code should look like this:

```
double* myDoubles[3];
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    myDoubles[i] = (double*) malloc(1000 * sizeof(double));
}
myDoubles[2][999] = 10.55;
```

Comment: sorry I want to alocate three arrays of 1000 doubles. The problems is not the *sizeof(double) I miss in the question not in the code.

Comment: No need to cast `malloc` return value.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using C++, use `std::vector` - See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

So the code becomes

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> myDoubles(3);
myDoubles[2].resize(1000);
myDoubles[2][999] = 10.55;
```

Perhaps you need to resize the other entries - I leave that exercise to you.

In addition you have no worries about memory leaks.